# Avoid "black squares" showing on images in Chrome when using Hardware Acceleration?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Recently a large number of users of my company's website have reported seeing black boxes on some images on our login page.

For example:

[image]

I've searched for solutions, and everyone suggests turning off Hardware acceleration in Chrome by going to `Settings | Advanced | Use hardware acceleration when available` and disabling this option, which of course I don't want to have to tell users of our website to do!

It seems like [this has been an on again/off again issue in Chrome since 2015](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/YENyxjH6QtE/jkSqQFEXBwAJ).

**Is there a way to avoid this issue using CSS, different image formats, or directives of some sort?**

EDIT: Some Additional information

- It's definitely reproducible on different machines running the same version of Chrome, with no extensions installed, with a new profile user, and in Incognito mode. But not on all machines - only some.
- The images in question are being loaded from a CSS Image sprite.
- Here's a dump of my GPU info, which has this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? is the image missing or something?

Comment: Hey... the image isn't missing, it just renders with that black square over top of it when hardware acceleration is enabled. It comes from a css image sprite. I'll try and get a working example up somewhere.

Comment: Is this reproducible on other hardware? Is it specific to a particular brand or model of GPU?

Comment: Maybe there is something up with the image sprite? I use sprites on all my sits and never seen this before

Comment: It's definitely reproducible on different machines running the same version of Chrome, with no extensions installed, with a new profile user, and in Incognito mode. But not on all machines - only some.

Comment: Chrome updates often, are you not allowed to upgrade chrome?

Comment: Yeah I can of course - but I'm just trying to see if there's a usable way to stop this happening for any end users, as this issue seems to intermittently show up in Chrome, and we'd like to avoid support calls about it.

Comment: Can you post `about:gpu` from one of the affected browsers, please?

Comment: Also, do you require GPU compositing or hardware acceleration for any features on your site? Eg, are you using `translateZ` or swipe gestures or anything "fancy" like that? Are you using `opacity`, by chance?

Comment: Well if this is a browser bug then I wouldn't worry about it since chrome updates often enough to kill it and chrome updates automatically. You probably try transform3d(0,0,0) that seems to fix some weird chrome issues, maybe this could be one of them but I don't think you need to spend too much time on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I've found 2 different solutions for our situation:

1. Remove the `border-radius` css attribute from styling these images
2. Stop using a CSS Image Sprite, and use an image or font instead to load these images from.

Comment: Can you wrap the image and set border radius on the wrapper?